# Using pointer inside a struct

Tags: c, struct

Suppose I have the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct
{
    int num;
} myObj;

typedef struct
{
    myObj *obj_ptr;
} myStruct;

void populate(myStruct *m1)
{
    m1->obj_ptr->num = 123;
}

int main()
{
    printf("Hello World");
    myStruct m1;
    populate(&m1);

    printf("%d", m1.obj_ptr->num);

    return 0;
}
```

The purpose of this code is I want to get an item e.g. `m1` populated instead of being returned by the `populate` function, hence the way it is coded.

I'm concerned about the line `m1.obj_ptr->num` since it doesn't seem like a good design. Are there any issues with this code even as I got it to run? Is there a better approach to this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is OK to have a pointer in a struct, you must however allocate memory for it:

```
void populate(myStruct *m1)
{
    m1->obj_ptr->num = 123;
}
```

is wrong, because `m1->obj_ptr` is not initialized. You can do this:

```
void populate(myStruct *m1)
{
    // always check for validity of arguments
    if(m1 == NULL)
        return;

    m1->obj_ptr = malloc(sizeof *m1->obj_ptr);
    if(m1->obj_ptr == NULL)
        return;

    m1->obj_ptr->num = 123;
}
```

I personally would make `populate` return 1 on success and 0 on failure, thus
the caller knows if the allocation was successful.

But you don't have to forget to free the memory:

```
int main()
{
    printf("Hello World");
    myStruct m1;
    populate(&m1);

    if(m1.obj_ptr)
        printf("%d", m1.obj_ptr->num);

    free(m1.obj_ptr);

    return 0;
}
```

If you say, you don't want to allocate memory in `populate`, then you have to
initialize the pointer prior to the call of the `populate`, like this:

```
int main()
{
    printf("Hello World");
    myStruct m1;
    myObj obj;

    m1.obj_ptr = &obj;

    populate(&m1);

    printf("%d", m1.obj_ptr->num);

    return 0;
}
```

But this has the disadvantage that you cannot return this struct to another
function. This would be incorrect:

```
myStruct get_me_a_struct(void)
{
    myStruct m1;
    myObj obj;

    m1.obj_ptr = &obj;

    populate(&m1);

    return m1;
}

void foo(void)
{
    myStruct m2 = get_me_a_struct();

    printf("%d\n", m2.obj_ptr->num); // <-- you cannot do that
}
```

because `m2.obj_ptr` would point to an invalid location. For that reason, using
`malloc` for the allocation is better.

Answer (score 1):

Two things; both within `populate()`:

First, nowhere are you allocating or deallocating the space for `obj_ptr` in your code. You simply set the value of `num` within in it and hope for the best. Before the line `m1->obj_ptr->num = 123;` allocate some memory for that `123` to live in with `m1->obj_ptr = malloc(sizeof(myObj))`. Without this, when you set `num` it is actually pointeing to an unknown memory address which is probably not set aside for your program to work in.

Similarly, `populate()` does not check whether `m1` is a valid address before assigning to its members. In this sample code, it is (only mostly) okay, because when you call `populate()` you are passing a reference(`&`) rather than a pointer(`*`), but, if you ever use it in the future, you may be calling with a pointer. So really, the first line in `populate()` needs to be `if(m1 != NULL)` with the rest of the function inside.

Comment: It is not necessarily unreasonable to assume that pointers are valid if the documentation for the function doesn't permit null pointers (and checking whether non-null pointers are valid is hard — expensive — work).